# If there is an orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $H$, then $H^T=H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Question: For any $n\times n$ real matrix $H$, if there is an orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $H$, then $H^T=H$?

Does this mean that $H$ is unitarily diagonalizable? If so, aren't orthogonal or skew symmetric matrices unitarily diagonalizable as well, so why is $H^T=H$(symmetric) true?

Comment: No and no. Why do you ask? From ehre that idea?

Comment: If $V = [v_1,\cdots,v_n]$ contains an onthonormal basis (which is obtained by the orthogonal one by scaling) consisting of eigenvectors of $H$, what is $HV$?

Comment: @DonAntonio So $H^T = H$ is false as well? Because the answers to the problem set I have here says that it is true...Perhaps the answer is wrong?

Comment: @Dirk $HV = VU$ for some diagonal matrix U? Then $U = V^{-1}HV$, so H is unitarily diagonalizable??

Comment: @TonyTarng My bad: now I realize you're asking about a **real** space and thus having orthogonal eigenvalues certainly $\;\implies H^t=H\;$ . In unitary spaces that's not true.

Comment: @DonAntonio So why does having orthogonal eigenvectors imply a matrix is symmetric? Do you mind elaborating a bit? I know that for a symmetric matrix, or more generally, for normal matrices, the eigenvectors can be chosen to be orthogonal, forming an orthogonal basis. But why is this other way around correct for real matrices?

Comment: @TonyTarng Because then there exists orthogonal $\;P\;$ s.t. $\;P^{-1}HP=D=\;$ diagonal (and **remember**: $\;P\;$ orthogonal means $\;P^{-1}=P\;$ ), and then$$H=PDP^{-1}\implies H^t=\left(PDP^{-1}\right)^t=\left(PDP^t\right)^t=PD^tP^t=PDP^t=PDP^{-1}=H$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you very much! I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: @DonAntonio May I ask something more: So a real matrix $A$ is only orthogonally diagonalizable iff $A$ is symmetric. However, a matrix $B$ is unitarily diagonalizable iff $B$ is a normal matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: @TonyTarng Yep: that is basically the spectral theorem

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, thanks!